# Lookup table for load cell calibration doesn't like negative numbers

Tags: lookup-tables

I have a load cell connected to an HX711 which all works fine. I am attempting to create a calibration table with 10 points holding the raw sensor output and the calibrated value using a set of weights. The load cell is bi-directional so it works in any direction so the output is positive and negative counts but the zero is not necessarily 0 output.

This all works fine when the numbers are all positive or all negative in each lookup table but fails when there is negative & positive numbers in the captured points. Eg, the output from the HX711 is positive 28,000 with no load. Add a load of 1kg and get a reading of -56,000. The next reading for 1Kg is say, -83,000. These are stored as {28,000, -56000, 83,000} in an array with the the calibrated {0, 1, 2} in another array.

Normally I interpolate the result based on finding which 2 numbers the raw count falls between. Everything works when the numbers are less than -56,000 and I get readings of 1 to 2kg. When the reading is greater than -56,000, it fails to calculate the reading and I end up with NAN.

It can also be the other way around with negative and then positive. (-56,000, 28,000, 55,000} for example.

How to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out not long after I posted the question and thought that the answer would help anyone else with this same issue. By comparing the 2 values for negative or positive as I stepped through the table and then swapping them around in the calculation, it works. The difference between 28,000 and -56,000 comes out as 84,000 and using this to do the maths works. I confirmed operation by applying 1kg and 2kd test loads. It reads in both directions pos or neg.